# Let X(X bar) denote the mean of a random sample of size 36 for Chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom.Find P(1.75 <X<2.5)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, chi-squared

My strategy was to prove that the given chi squared distribution converges to a normal distribution and then approximate the probability as a Normal distribution, not sure if that's the correct way to do it. I am so confused with this question, would appreciate the help!

I need to find P(1.75 < X < 2.5) but I am confused as to how I do it here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The description of $\ \bar{X}\ $ in the title of your question isn't completely clear, but the only sense I can make of it is that
$$
\bar{X}=\frac{1}{36}\sum_{j=1}^{36}Z_i
$$
where $\ Z_1,Z_2,\dots,Z_{36}\ $ are independent random variables with $\ Z\sim\chi_2^2\ $—that is each $\ Z_i\ $ follows a chi-squared distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom. Now the  chi-squared distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom is just that of the sum of the squares of two independent standard normal variates.  It follows that $\ \sum_\limits{j=1}^{36}Z_i\ $ must have the same distribution as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{72}Y_i^2\ ,
$$
where $\ Y_i\ $ are independent standard normal variates—that is, a chi-squared distribution with $72$ degrees of freedom.  That number of degrees of freedom is sufficiently large, however, that the distribution should be reasonably well approximated by a normal distribution with mean $\ 72\ $ and standard deviation $\ 12\ $, so your strategy of using that approximation should be acceptable.

The exact probability is given by
\begin{align}
P(1.75<\bar{X}<2.75)&=P\left(36\times1.75<\sum_{j=1}^{36}Z_i<36\times2.75\right)\\
&=\chi_{72}^2\left(99\right)-\chi_{72}^2\left(63\right)\ ,
\end{align}
which you can evaluate either by looking up the values of $\ \chi_{72}^2\left(99\right)\ $ and $\ \chi_{72}^2\left(63\right)\ $ in a table of the chi-squared distributions, or plugging the arguments $\ 99\ $ and $\ 63\ $ into a chi-squared calculator, such as the one provided by WolframAlfa, which gives [$\ \chi_{72}^2\left(99\right)\approx0.980857\ $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+chisquare+with+72+dof%2C+prob+x%3C99) and
[$\ \chi_{72}^2\left(63\right)\approx0.233443\ $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+chisquare+with+72+dof%2C+prob+x%3C63). The normal approximation, on the other hand, gives [$\ \mathcal{N}_{(72,12)}(99)\approx0.987776\ $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+normal+distribution%2C+mean%3D72%2C+sd%3D12%2C+prob+x%3C99) and [$\ \mathcal{N}_{(72,12)}(63)\approx0.226627\ $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+normal+distribution%2C+mean%3D72%2C+sd%3D12%2C+prob+x%3C63), resulting in an approximation which is about $\ 1.8\%\ $ too high.

**Addendum**

I've just realised that you can use WolframAlfa to get the values of $\ \chi_{72}^2\left(99\right)-\chi_{72}^2\left(63\right)\ $ and $\ \mathcal{N}_{(72,12)}(99)-$$\,\mathcal{N}_{(72,12)}(63)\ $ directly, without calculating the upper and lower bounds separately. The results to $6$ decimal places are [$\ 0.747414\ $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+chisquare+with+72+dof%2C+prob+63%3Cx%3C99) for the first quantity, and [$\ 0.761148\ $](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+normal+distribution%2C+mean%3D72%2C+sd%3D12%2C+prob+63%3Cx%3C99) for the second.

Comment: I'm so sorry but the X is basically x̄( X bar) but I couldn't figure out how to place the symbol as it wouldn't let me. Would that cause any changes to the answer?

Comment: The normal approximation I got for the upper bound was 0.9332, did I possibly do something wrong?

Comment: If $\ \bar{X}\ $ is meant to be the sample mean, then it's what was calling $\ X\ $ in my original answer.  I've now updated it by replacing $\ X\ $ with $\ \bar{X}\ $.  I checked the normal approximation upper bound by plugging $\ \frac{99-72}{12}=2.25\ $ into this online calculator https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal, which returned the value $\ 0.98778\ $, the same as that I got from WolframAlpha, rounded to $5$ decimal places.  How did you get $\ 0.9332\ $?